# including freetype-gl.h causes wglew errors

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, freetype

I've integrated all the needed files to use `freetype-gl.h`directly into my OpenGL project, but when I try to build the program, I receive 262 errors complaining about`wglew.h`. A sample of the errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'  c:\bar\includes\glew110\include\gl\wglew.h  113 1   Foo
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\bar\glew110\include\gl\wglew.h   113 1   Foo
error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\bar\includes\glew110\include\gl\wglew.h  113 1   Foo
error C2065: 'HDC' : undeclared identifier  c:\bar\glew110\include\gl\wglew.h 113   1   Foo
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'hDC' c:\bar\includes\glew110\include\gl\wglew.h  113 1   Foo
```

And in my class, just this header causes the problem with `wglew.h`:

```
#include "freetype-gl.h" // causes all the errors
```

Comment: Could you post your include section of the code? First thing come to my mind is you included glew.h after freetype-gl.h. And probably freetype-gl has gl and/or glu library included inside. Try to include glew.h first

Answer (score 0):

This solution solved a wglew error for me, not sure if it's the same problem.

Try adding the wglew.h include line to the same file as your other include line for freetype-gl.h, and in this order:

```
#include <Windows.h> // maybe not needed
#define GLEW_STATIC // maybe not needed
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GL/wglew.h"
#include "freetype-gl.h"
// other includes below
```